# ¿como puedo gastar menos memoria en este problema de grafos?

Tags: c++, array

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cstring>

#define TAM 1000000

using namespace std;

void dfs( int,bool[] );

vector<int> adj[TAM];

int cont, N;

int main( ) {
  int I,i,a,b,p;
  char oso;

  cin >> N >> I;

  bool visit[N] = { false };

  while( I-- ) {
    cin >> oso;

    switch( oso ) {
    case 'A':
      cin >> a >> b;
      adj[a].push_back( b );
      adj[b].push_back( a );
      break;

    case 'E':
      cin >> p;
      cont = 1;
      dfs( p, visit );
      memset( visit, 0, N * I );
      cout << cont << endl;
      break;      
    }     
  }
}

void dfs( int nodo,bool visit[] ) {
  visit[nodo] = true;

  for( auto &k:adj[nodo] ) {
    if( visit[k] == false ) {
      dfs(k,visit);
      ++cont;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta toda los detalles que proporcionas, yo diría que haciendo `#define TAM 1`. ¿ Puedes dar algo mas de información ?

Comment: El código no compila. si `adj` es un vector de enteros, `adj[a]` no tendrá un método `push_back` al que llamar ya que `int` no posee dicho método...

Comment: bueno es un problema de omegaUp llamado noticias y la cantidad maxima de datos que se va a ingresar es 1,000,000, y se tiene que verificar la cantidad de conexiones entre nodos, para eso es la lista de adyacencia(el arreglo de vectores)

Answer (score 0):

No das demasiado contexto sobre el problema en el que estás trabajando, pero echando un vistazo al código, la matriz de adyacentes podría ser mucho menor: si "a" es adyacente a "b", entonces "b" es adyacente a "a", como se puede ver en estas dos líneas de código:

```
  adj[a].push_back( b );
  adj[b].push_back( a );
```

Esto quiere decir que podrías guardar únicamente si "a" es adyacente a "b", ya que si este es el caso, "b" es adyacente a "a":

```
adj[a].push_back( b );
```

Así el tamaño de adj sería mucho menor (en vez de ser una matriz MxM, podría ser únicamente un vector de tamaño M)

Comment: si tienes razon, pero es necesario hacerlo de esa manera para que el algoritmo funcione y pueda buscar todos los nodos adyacentes a un n dado, al menos en la forma que lo pense